# UI Freezing and Computation Really Slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

I'm writing a program, that should replace or remove some entries from a logfile.txt. 
The code is working fine ( at least for small LogFiles). If i use a big file (like 27 MB) its getting very slow and the UI freeze. I cant click anything.

On Button click i execute this method:

```
       private string delete_Lines(string[] lines, string searchString)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {

            if (lines[i].Contains(searchString))
            {
                rtbLog.Text += "Deleting(row " + (i + 1) + "):\n" + lines[i] + "\n";
                progressBar1.Value += 1;
                if (cbDB == true)
                {
                    while (is_next_line_block(lines, i) == true)
                    {
                        i++;
                        rtbLog.Text += lines[i] + "\n";
                        progressBar1.Value += 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                res += lines[i]+"\n";
                progressBar1.Value += 1;
            }

        }
        tssLbl.Text = "Done!";
        rtbLog.Text += "...Deleting finished\n";
        return res;
    }
```

Lines is the array of the logfile i am trying to clean up. every entry is a single row .  tssLbl is a notification label and rtbLog is a richTextBox, where i'am tracking which row i am deleting.

is_next_line_block is just another method, which is checking of the next lines are part of the block i want to delete. The params of this method are the whole lines array and the line position.

```
private bool is_next_line_block(string[] lines, int curIndex)
    {
        if (curIndex < lines.Length-1)
        {
            if (lines[curIndex + 1].StartsWith(" "))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Have anybody any idea, what is causing that freezes and is slowing down the program? I know, that i could speed my code up by parallelizing it, but i cant imagine, that it takes so long to check up a 27 MB txt file without parallelism.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` _does_ use threads, and it's specifically designed to allow for progress updates to the UI. If you are having trouble figuring that out, ask a question specifically about that. As for performance, using some other threading model isn't going to change the performance. If it takes very long to process 27MB, then either that file is on the slowest disk ever, or your processing is too slow. In any case, you need to narrow this example down to something simpler, and focus on one issue at a time. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Seriously consider moving the code to a separate class and making the call to that class require the appropriate parameters instead of how you're doing it now. Now instance this class and call it via a `Task.Factory.Start()` and tell me if it's still slowing down your app. Remember to add a `.ContinueWith` if you need to set/unset visual cues (e.g. progress bar, etc).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I edit my question and codeblock, so it can be read better. ty for the suggestion.

at code4life: Just to be sure, that i understand you correctly:
you want me to move my whole code (expect the parts from the ui) to a new class and make my computations there? To be honest i dont know what you mean by  Task.Factory.Start() and what exactly does .ContinueWith?

Comment: Given your edit, what is your _specific_ question? Asking "any ideas or suggestions?" is a bit broad and vague, to say the least. Please also go back and reread the links I offered in my first comment.

Comment: I already wrote down my problem in the introduction, but i edit the thread another time, maybe its now clear enough. I Also read the links you posted.

Comment: @code4life I split the file in 2 classes. the first class ( the Form1 class) is handling the ui.
The second one is handling the the clean up of the log file. TBH i dont know how to call Task.Factory.Start() properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here:

1. You are reading the whole file in buffer (array of string), I am guessing you are calling File.ReadAllLines(). Reading big files in buffer will slow you down, as well as in extreme case run you out of memory.
2. You are using += operation for your rich textbox Text property. That is time consuming operation as UI has to render the whole rich text box every time you update the text property that way. Better option is to use string builder to load these text, and update rich text box periodically.

To fix this you need to read the file as stream. Progress can be monitored based on bytes read instead of line position. You can run the read operation async and monitor progression on a timer, as shown in example below.

```
private void RunFileOperation(string inputFile, string search)
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    int progress = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Filesize serves as max value to check progress
    progressBar1.Maximum = (int)(new FileInfo(inputFile).Length);
    t.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            rtbLog.Text = sb.ToString();
            progressBar1.Value = progress;
            if (progress == progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                t.Enabled = false;
                tssLbl.Text = "done";
            }
        };
    //update every 0.5 second       
    t.Interval = 500;
    t.Enabled = true;
    // Start async file read operation
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => delete_Lines(inputFile, search, ref progress, ref sb));      
}

private void delete_Lines(string fileName, string searchString, ref int progress, ref StringBuilder sb)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = file.ReadLine();
            progress = (int)file.BaseStream.Position;
            if (line.Contains(searchString))
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Deleting(row {0}):\n{1}", (i + 1), line);
                // Change this algorithm for nextline check
                // Do this when it is next line, i.e. in this line.
                // "If" check above can check if (line.startswith(" "))...
                // instead of having to do it nextline next here.
                /*if (cbDB == true)
                {
                    while (is_next_line_block(lines, i) == true)
                    {
                        i++;
                        rtbLog.Text += lines[i] + "\n";
                        progressBar1.Value += 1;
                    }
                }*/
            }
        }
    }           
    sb.AppendLine("...Deleting finished\n");
}
```

Comment: working like a charm. ty rly. need to make some adjustment, but i guess the main work is done. Ill post the working code when i'm finished, just in case somebody is interested in a working result of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to your question on `Task.Factory.Start()` usage, it's done this way (generally):

```
// you might need to wrap this in a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (see below)
// if you are not calling from the main UI thread
CallSomeMethodToSetVisualCuesIfYouHaveOne();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // code in this block will run in a background thread...
}
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
   // if you called the task from the UI thread, you're probably
   // ok if you decide not to wrap the optional method call below
   // in a dispatcher begininvoke... 
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
   {
       CallSomeMethodToUnsetYourVisualCuesIfYouHaveAnyLOL();
   }));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ty for the explanation. already fixed it, but ill keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for the help, especially loopedcode, That's the working version (Took loopedcode's code and made some edit):

```
        private void RunFileOperation(string inputFile, string search)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        {
            rtbLog.Text = "Start Deleting...\n";
        }


        // Filesize serves as max value to check progress
        progressBar1.Maximum = (int)(new FileInfo(inputFile).Length);
        t.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            rtbLog.Text += sb.ToString();
            progressBar1.Value = progress;
            if (progress == progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                t.Enabled = false;
                tssLbl.Text = "done";
            }
        };
        //update every 0.5 second       
        t.Interval = 500;
        t.Enabled = true;
        // Start async file read operation
        if (rbtnDelete.Checked)
        {
            if (cbDelete.Checked)
            {
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => delete_Lines(inputFile, search, ref progress, ref sb, ref res1));
            }
    }
    else 
    {
       //..do something
    }

    private void delete_Lines(string fileName, string searchString, ref int progress, ref      StringBuilder sb, ref StringBuilder res1)
    {
    bool checkNextLine=false;
        using (var file = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (!file.EndOfStream)
            {
                i++;
                var line = file.ReadLine();
                progress = (int)file.BaseStream.Position;
                if (line.Contains(searchString))
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("Deleting(row {0}):\n{1}\n", (i), line);
                    checkNextLine = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cbDB && checkNextLine && line.StartsWith(" "))
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("{0}\n", line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkNextLine = false;
                        res1.AppendLine(line);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        sb.AppendLine("\n...Deleting finished!);
    }
```